# Replace a big chunk of html

Tags: c#

I have a big chunk html code that I would like to replace from time to time with c#. I have made my own method for that where I post in htmlcode as string and than I do find and replace. I don't se this as a good approach and I wonder if anybody have a tip on any better approach or libary that I can use?

Comment: You may find [CSQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) useful or helpful.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are doing?  Right now its pretty unclear.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack was the answer, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial approach is `Regex.Replace()`. With Regular Expressions you can search for a specific pattern in Text (or HTML in this case) and replace it with something else.

The more in-depth approach is to use **HtmlAgilityPack**. It's a 3rd party component that creates a DOM from the HTML you throw at it and handles incomplete syntaxes far more better than a XML-based parser or a RegEx would. With the DOM your able to selectively extract data you want or replace certain nodes in the logical tree with new stuff. It's available at NuGet and on Codeplex: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Be aware that the HtmlAgilityPack hasn´t been updated since a while.